# This error is showing after deploying from localhost to Vercell! How to solve it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, vite

After deploying my MERN stack project's server code from localhost to vercell it shows this error! How to solve it?

> Access to fetch at 'https://blood-management-server.vercel.app/donor' from origin 'https://bloodcare-bangladesh.web.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Client Side Code:

```
    const handleDonorRegistration = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const image =  event.target.files;
        const name = event.target.name.value;
        const email = event.target.email.value;
        const phone = event.target.phone.value;
        const bloodGroup = event.target.bloodGroup.value;
        const birthday = event.target.birthday.value;
        const lastDonationDate = event.target.lastDonationDate.value;
        const donorWeight = event.target.donorWeight.value;
        const height = event.target.height.value;
        const countryName = event.target.countryName.value;
        const districtName = event.target.districtName.value;
        const donor = {image, name, email, phone, bloodGroup, gender, birthday, lastDonationDate, donorWeight, height, countryName, districtName }


        fetch('https://blood-management-server.vercel.app/donor', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(donor)
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                Swal.fire({
                    title: "Congratulations!",
                    text: "You are in the donor list!",
                    icon: "success"
                  });
                  event.target.reset();
            })
    }
```

Server code:

```
const express = require("express");
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require("mongodb");
const cors = require("cors");
const {} = require("mongodb");
require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//Middleware
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "https://bloodcare-bangladesh.web.app",
  methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type"],
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://bloodcare-bangladesh.web.app');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  next();
});

const uri = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.BD_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}@bloodcare-bd.gduqg86.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

// Create a MongoClient with a MongoClientOptions object to set the Stable API version
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  serverApi: {
    version: ServerApiVersion.v1,
    strict: true,
    deprecationErrors: true,
  },
});

async function run() {
  try {
    // Connect the client to the server (optional starting in v4.7)
    client.connect();

    const database = client.db("userDB");
    const userCollections = database.collection("users");
    const donorCollection = client.db("userDB").collection("donors");

    app.get("/donors", async (req, res) => {
      const query = {};
      const cursor = donorCollection.find(query);
      const donors = await cursor.toArray();
      res.send(donors);
    });

    app.post("/user", async (req, res) => {
      const user = req.body;
      console.log("new user added:", user);
      const result = await userCollections.insertOne(user);
    });

    app.post("/donor", async (req, res) => {
      const donor = req.body;
      console.log("added new Donor:", donor);
      const result = await donorCollection.insertOne(donor);
      res.send(result);
    });

    // Send a ping to confirm a successful connection
    await client.db("admin").command({ ping: 1 });
    console.log(
      "Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!"
    );
  } finally {
    // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
    // await client.close();
  }
}
run().catch(console.log);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("server is running for blood management....!");
});

app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Curd server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message and your server codes, it looks like you only listed `Content Type` for allowed headers for your server:

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "https://bloodcare-bangladesh.web.app",
  methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type"],
};
```

but then you are setting the headers again further down:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://bloodcare-bangladesh.web.app');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  next();
});
```

So, it's most likely an error from the inconsistencies.

**Fix:** Use your `cors` package for ALL of your CORS configurations, and if you want to use those extra headers, add it to the `allowedHeaders` in the `corsOptions`.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Maybe deploying to vercel was causing that problem, after deploy to Render everything to working fine.